# Android - Title text not shown in Action Bar after customization

Tags: android, android-actionbar, customization

I'm trying to customize a bit my Action Bar, but by doing this, the title in the Action Bar vanish, while the background color correctly change.

Does anyone know where's the problem?

Thank you in advance.

Here is my .xml file:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
   <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBar" parent="AppBaseTheme">
  <item name="android:background">@color/ActionBarColor</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your action bar theme should have a parent of `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar`, rather than `AppBaseTheme`.